# PRTG - Windows IIS Application sensor fault

Tags: iis, network-monitoring, wmi

I have two sensors that are giving me the same alarm.

> WMI: No result set (code: PE016) -- PerfCounter: No data to return.
>   (Performance Counter error 0x800007D5)

I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this or how to resolve it. I have checked the PRTG Knowledge base and have tried the fixes on here.

It points towards being some kind of WMI fault.

https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/3713-i-have-tried-a-lot-of-things-to-fix-my-wmi-what-else-can-i-try-to-avoid-reinstalling-windows

I've checked and restarted the WMI service and all the dependencies. I'm at a bit of a loss. I've been googling hard but can't seem to find anything that works.

If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

Comment: You can download `WMI Tester` from paessler.com to see if you have a general WMI problem on this machine. Start the tester on the PRTG server and test your IIS server. Also: is `Remote Registry Service` running? Are these machines on the same domain?